# Comparing two tables and outputting to a new column

Tags: case

This is just returning Y or N and not comparing the data directly

tblViewLearners  (this intID = intLearnerID in the other table)

```
IntID   -   FirstName    -  Surname   -  Course    - Dob    - address     - nationality
701271      Julie           Barnett      Physics     NULL       NULL          NULL
345239      Rachel          Smith        Physics     NULL       NULL          NULL
240259      David           Feffer       Maths       NULL       NULL          NULL
```

tblAWARDSLearner  (basically if the learner made it to this table that have a 'DISTINCTION')

```
 intID   -  intLearnerID    -  dateawarded
 2402       701271             21/04/1992
 1032       345239             01/01/2010
```

MY GOAL

```
IntID   -   FirstName    -  Surname   -  Course     - DISTINCTION Awarded
701271      Julie           Barnett      Physics          Yes
345239      Rachel          Smith        Physics          Yes
240259      David           Feffer       Maths            No
```

THE CODE

```
SELECT Y.intID
FROM
(
SELECT    A.* ,   
CASE 
        WHEN B.intLearnerID IS NULL THEN 'N' 
        ELSE 'Y' 
END 'DISTINCTION Awarded' x
FROM 
    tblviewlearners A
    LEFT JOIN tblAWARDSLearner B
    ON A.intID = B.intLearnerID

)AS Y;
```

I also with to join it with another table but will cross that bridge once the above is working, its worth noting that the above tables have already been declared further up so when I do join I don't need to include it in a FROM and just compare the table columns more directly (I think this is correct).   However I want to get the above working first.

Comment: If the nature of your problem is the same as the other question, I don't believe you should post a new question, but rather adapt the answers from the existing question to your individual problem. StackOverflow isn't a forum to get help on your individual problem, but rather more a place to ask questions that haven't been asked so they can be answered for others (with similar problems) to find later.

Comment: I would but I cannot add the above code and table data to the comment box, we are both having the same problem but in my case its different.